# Adding values to column filter of a list

Tags: 2010, list-definition, view

Ive created some custom xsl for a view in a project i am working on.  One of the columns shows a custom message depending on some date comparisons i am performing against other columns in the xsl.  Ive noticed that the custom messages are not present when using the column header to filter.  How can i make these values available in the header filter for this column. Is it possible?

Heres my code

```
<xsl:variable name="ExpiryDate" select="number(concat(substring(string($thisNode/@ExpiryDate),7,4),substring(string($thisNode/@ExpiryDate),4,2),substring-before(string($thisNode/@ExpiryDate),'/')))"/>
      <xsl:variable name="TodaysDate" select="number(ddwrt:FormatDateTime(ddwrt:Today(),2057,'yyyyMMdd'))" />

      <xsl:variable name="DateDelta">
        <xsl:call-template name="getDayDelta">
          <xsl:with-param name="paramDateA" select="concat(substring(string($thisNode/@ExpiryDate),7,4),'-', substring(string($thisNode/@ExpiryDate),4,2),'-', substring-before(string($thisNode/@ExpiryDate),'/'))"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="paramDateB" select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(ddwrt:Today(),1033,'yyyy-MM-dd')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$ExpiryDate &lt;= $TodaysDate">
          <xsl:attribute name="style">color:red;</xsl:attribute>
          DO NOT USE
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$ExpiryDate &gt; $TodaysDate and $DateDelta &lt;= 30">
              <xsl:attribute name="style">color:orange;</xsl:attribute>
              EXPIRES IN 30 DAYS OR LESS
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:attribute name="style">color:green;</xsl:attribute>
              GOOD TO USE
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
```

Heres the column populated

[image]

Heres the header filter which is missing the values

[image]

Comment: Can you show your xsl code or at least the parts that are not working?

Comment: @RyanErickson its all working.  I see the values and they are correct.  The problem is the values are not in the header drop down so i cant filter on these values

Comment: This is because the filtering is done on the server before the xsl transform. Could you change that to be a computed column rather than defining the values in the xsl?

Comment: @RyanErickson thanks for that.  I thought as much.  I dont think i can make it a calculated column as it does some date comparisons using the current date.  As far as i know you cant do this server side